# Is there a way to have 2 Color Scale conditional formatting affect Font color instead of Cell color?

Tags: colors, formatting, conditional-statements, scale, percentage

First and foremost, thanks for your attention :)

What I would like to do is having conditional formatting based on percentage from 0 to 100%. I'd need 0% to show up red and 100% to show up green. 
The problem I have with the current conditional formatting is that it affects the background color of the cell. What I need it to do is to change the Font Color depending on the percentage, and leave the original color of the cell intact.

Is there a way to do so?

Using Excel 2010

Many thanks,
Francis